# Why isn't my picture responsive in bootstrap 4.6?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make my image responsive but it isn't.  Can anybody help?

My code:

```
<!doctype html>    
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>         
        <meta charset="utf-8>           
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />          
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">          
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="restless-inc.css">     
    </head>     
    <body>
    
        <div class="container-fluid">
        
            <img src="images/dog3.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;" alt="...">
        
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Thanks for any help anybody might offer.

Regards

Nick

Comment: Need more information, define "it isnt" responsive. Also anything in `restless-inc.css` in regards to images tags?

Comment: You may want to check your code again (you need to close `<meta charset="utf-8>`) and view any image tag css in `restless-inc.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who responded to my question.  The problem was with the instruction max-width:100% and I was using very small images so they didn't scale up.  When I changed the instruction to width:100% the images scaled up and were much more responsive. Again thanks and my regards to all.

Answer (score -1):

Try the class `img-responsive`, maybe you can combine it with your actual class

Comment: He's using 4.6.0 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/images/